# R package moved from windows 64- bit to 32-bit no longer works

Tags: r, 32bit-64bit, r-package

I am working on creating a portable shiny app by referring to [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/).

I have a 64bit system and the target systems can be both 64bit and 32bit. I installed all packages in the portable apps library. Since the target machines don't have any internet connection.

On the target machine all packages load perfectly, except for `prophet` which gives error

[image]

So I see that it runs the r.exe in bin folder for whatever reason

[image]

So I run it directly which gives me this error

[image]

I know the system is 32bit. As a test case I ran the shiny app by calling on the 32bit R.exe without prophet package - and it worked perfectly.

[image]

So my question is

**How do I load Prophet?**

My speculation is that it tries to run the 64bit R.exe and fails, if so why are all the other packages load perfectly?

If this is the issue then how do I point it to the 32 bit R.exe?

Comment: What happens if you set `R_ARCH_BIN="/i386"` as a global env var (within the portable-R instance)?

Comment: @r2evans Oh I didn't know about this, I will check it out tomorrow at office. So once I do this `R_ARCH_BIN="/i386"` will it be set global? or do I have to declare it any other way?

Comment: I'm not proficient with portable-R, but judging by the code you have in one of your pictures, it will use it if present.

Comment: Specifically, `system2(file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "bin", Sys.getenv("R_ARCH_BIN")))` defaults to something like `"c:/R/R-33~1.3/bin"` b/c `R_ARCH_BIN` is often not set. If set, it should return something like `"c:/R/R-33~1.3/bin/i386"`.